# How do I solve the port in use problem in MySQL without XAMPP?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, xampp

I am learning MySQL, and I am new in this field. I am not sure what is it XAMPP yet nor how to use it. I am trying to download MySQL on my windows but I have this problem that "port in use".

I am not sure what to do?

I deleted MySQL files from my local desk and uninstalled MySQL, until I figure out what to do.

Comment: xammp has already a mysql or mariadb server on port 3306, so there is no need to install another one, but you can run multiple instances if you like see https://serverfault.com/questions/823555/how-to-install-and-start-multiple-mysql-instances-on-windows-2012

Comment: Have you tried running MySQL on a different port?

Answer (score 0):

I try to explain it in a simple way (not by using netstat)
first go the services (services.msc) and try to find out if there is a service named mysql. if yes... stop it.
Then try to open your xampp panel. Start the mysql service (port 3306).

if the port is still in use, try the following command in the command prompt (cmd):
mysql -V

Does a result come? Then mysql is probably still installed. Not bad!

in the terminal:

mysql -u root -p

Login possible? Good! Then just use the installed version and learn the basics of PHP and MySQL. If you don't know Xampp yet... Start small! PHP is enough for the beginning. Databases etc. will come later automatically.

Small note: Windows is not recommended for beginners in PHP... (my opinion). In Nodejs etc. no problem... but for PHP, MySQL Windows really sucks beginners! Remedy is Docker (a little bit!)